# How do I Validate textInput in a Shiny app?

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I have a shiny app that prompts users to enter a USGS NWIS Site Number, and then returns a map of nearby stations and a bar chart of historical stream flow around that site. I am having a hard time validating user input of the Site Number to textInput(). I need to prompt users to try again (and not accept the input) when users either don't enter a number and hit submit, enter an incorrect number (that doesn't exist in the NWIR database), or enter a number with leading or trailing spaces. Where should I put the call to 'validate' in this app?

```
##############################################################################
# Libraries
##############################################################################
rm(list=ls())
list.of.packages <- c("RColorBrewer",
                      "dataRetrieval",
                      "curl",
                      "repr",
                      "maps",
                      "dplyr",
                      "ggplot2",
                      "leaflet",
                      "leafem",
                      "raster",
                      "raster",
                      "shiny",
                      "htmlwidgets",
                      "devtools",
                      "shinycustomloader",
                      "shinydashboard",
                      "shinyjs",
                      "DT",
                      "spData",
                      "sf",
                      "shinythemes",
                      "plotly")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
lapply(list.of.packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

##############################################################################
# UI Side
##############################################################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  #titlePanel("USGS Gages Annual Flow Peak Tool"),
  h1(id="big-heading", "USGS Gages Annual Flow Peak Tool"),
  tags$style(HTML("
      @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Cabin:400,700');

      h1 {
        font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 1.1;
        color: #006F41;
      }

    ")),

  # side panel
  sidebarPanel(


    textInput(inputId ="site_no", 
              label = "Site Number", 
              width = '400px',
              #value=01615000,
              placeholder = "Please enter the NWIS Site Number."),
    textInput(inputId ="years_of_records", 
              label = "Years of Records", 
              width = '400px',
              value = 30,
              placeholder = "How many years of Records would you like?"),
    textInput(inputId ="da_epsilon", 
              label = "Drainage Area Epsilon", 
              width = '400px',
              value = 0.25,
              placeholder = "What is the Drainage Area Epsilon?"),
    textInput(inputId ="bbox_delta", 
              label = "Bounding Box Delta - Degrees", 
              width = '400px',
              value = 1,
              placeholder = "What is the Bounding Box delta?"),

    actionButton(
      inputId = "submit_loc",
      label = "Submit"
    ),
    downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data'),
    h4(''),
    dataTableOutput('table01'),
    width = 3),

  # main panel
  mainPanel(
    leafletOutput('map01', width = "110%", height="500px"),
    br(),
    plotlyOutput('hist01', width = "110%")
      )
)

##############################################################################
# Server Side
##############################################################################
server <- function(input,output, session){
  shinyjs::hide("downloadData")
  observeEvent(input$submit_loc, {

    cat("START\n")

    validate(
      need(input$site_no, 'Enter a Site Number!')
    )

    SITE_NUM=input$site_no
    SITE_URL <- paste0("https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/inventory/?site_no=",SITE_NUM,"&agency_cd=USGS")
    paraCode <- "00060"
    years_of_records <- as.numeric(input$years_of_records)
    da_epsilon <- as.numeric(input$da_epsilon)
    bbox_delta <- as.numeric(input$bbox_delta) # Degrees
    cat("Showing", SITE_NUM, "NWIS id",
        "\nUsing URL:", SITE_URL,
        "\nwith ", years_of_records, "years of records",
        "\n& Drainage Area of: ", da_epsilon,
        "\n& Bounding Box delta of: ", bbox_delta, "\n")
    # CODE TO MAKE DATA FRAME

    # Get site coordinates to build Bbox
    site_data <- whatNWISsites(siteNumber=SITE_NUM, parameterCd=paraCode)
    site_lat <- site_data$dec_lat_va
    site_long <- site_data$dec_long_va
    site_data$site_url <- SITE_URL

    # Get site drainage area
    site_summary <- readNWISsite(siteNumber=SITE_NUM)
    site_da <- site_summary$drain_area_va


    # need to use SIG FIGS --- Otherwise the curl command gets confused.
    bBox <- c(signif(site_long - bbox_delta,7),
              signif(site_lat - bbox_delta,7),
              signif(site_long + bbox_delta,7),
              signif(site_lat + bbox_delta,7))

    bbox_shiny <- c(bBox[1],bBox[3],bBox[2],bBox[4])

    # Get site metadata for the Bbox
    para_sites <- as.data.frame(whatNWISsites(bBox=bBox, parameterCd=paraCode))
    para_sites$gtype = paraCode #gtype: gage type (stage, flow, ...etc)

    # Filter the retrieved USGS gages based on the defined criteria
    sites_meta <- whatNWISdata(siteNumber=para_sites$site_no, parameterCd=paraCode)
    sites_meta_years <- sites_meta[(sites_meta['end_date'] - sites_meta['begin_date']) > (years_of_records * 365.0),]
    sites_summary <- readNWISsite(siteNumber=sites_meta_years$site_no)
    sites_selected <- sites_summary[((1-da_epsilon)* site_da) <= sites_summary['drain_area_va'] & sites_summary['drain_area_va'] <= ((1+da_epsilon)* site_da), ]
    # Separate surrounding sites
    site_surrounding <- sites_selected[sites_selected$site_no != SITE_NUM, ]

    # Append URL 
    for(i in 1:nrow(sites_selected)){
      sites_selected_no <- as.character(sites_selected$site_no)
      sites_selected$site_url <- paste0("https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/inventory/?site_no=",sites_selected_no,"&agency_cd=USGS")
    }

    # Separate central site
    red_site <- sites_selected[sites_selected$site_no == paste(SITE_NUM),]

    # GET PEAK STREAMFLOW DATA
    peak_ts <- readNWISpeak(input$site_no)
    cols = c("site_no","peak_dt","peak_va","gage_ht")
    peak_ts <- peak_ts[,cols]
    names(peak_ts) <- c("Site Number", "Peak Streamflow: Date", "Peak streamflow (cfs)", "Gage Height (feet)")
    output$table01 <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(peak_ts, 
                  selection = "single",
                  extensions = 'Responsive',
                  rownames=FALSE,
                  options=list(stateSave = FALSE, 
                               autoWidth = TRUE,
                               lengthMenu = c(10, 10)))
    })

    shinyjs::show("downloadData")

    data <- sites_selected
    # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste0(input$site_no, "_data.csv")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data, file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )


    output$map01 <- renderLeaflet({

      leaflet(sites_selected) %>% 
        clearShapes() %>%
        addTiles() %>% 
        leafem::addMouseCoordinates() %>% 
        leafem::addHomeButton(extent(us_states),"Zoom to Home")%>%
        fitBounds(~min(dec_long_va), ~min(dec_lat_va), ~max(dec_long_va), ~max(dec_lat_va)) %>% 
        addCircleMarkers(data = red_site,
                         lng= ~dec_long_va,
                         lat = ~dec_lat_va,
                         color='red',
                         popup= paste0( red_site$station_nm,
                                        "<br>", "USGS site: ", red_site$site_no,
                                        "<br>", "<a href='", red_site$site_url,
                                        "' target='_blank'>", "USGS URL</a>"),
                         label = red_site$station_nm) %>% 
        addCircleMarkers(data = site_surrounding,
                         lng= ~dec_long_va,
                         lat = ~dec_lat_va,
                         color='blue',
                         popup= paste0( site_surrounding$station_nm,
                                        "<br>", "USGS site: ", site_surrounding$site_no,
                                        "<br>", "<a href='", site_surrounding$site_url,
                                        "' target='_blank'>", "USGS URL</a>"),
                         label = site_surrounding$station_nm)
    })

    peak_named <- cbind(red_site[,"station_nm"], peak_ts)
    names(peak_named[1]) <- c("Station Name")
    chart_title=paste(peak_named[1,1], peak_named[1,2],': Peak streamflow (cfs)')
    qSub <-  reactive({
      peak_named
    })

    # histogram
    output$hist01 <- renderPlotly({

      ggplot(data=qSub()) +
        geom_bar(aes(x=peak_ts[,"Peak Streamflow: Date"],y=peak_ts[,"Peak streamflow (cfs)"]),
                 stat="identity", 
                 width=125) +
        ylab('Peak streamflow (cfs)') +
        xlab('Date') +
        # xlim(min(qDat$drain_area_va), max(qDat$drain_area_va))+
        ggtitle(chart_title)+
        theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial", color = "grey20", size=12, face="bold"))

    })
  })



  output$map01 <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 4) %>% addTiles()
  })
}

##############################################################################
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
##############################################################################
```

Comment: why not use `selectInput` where you can restrict the choices to only the valid sites?

Comment: Great suggestion - unfortunately, there's thousands of valid sites. Users will have some familiarity with the numbering system and will primarily be entering in wrong values simply by mistake

Comment: But user can actually use `selectInput` like a `textInput` and dropdown choices will be filtered according to typed text. If typed text doesn't match with anything then dropdown choices wil not show anything. Basically user can't enter bad data.

Comment: Interesting... I'll give this a shot. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to use `selectInput` where you restrict the choices to valid sites. `selectInput` can be used as a text search where the dropdown list will be filtered based on user input text.

Below image shows what I mean. Note that it works even if you have `multiple = FALSE` in `selectInput` -

[image]

As to answer your question -

You need to create a vector of valid `sites` and use following in an upstream `reative` or downstream in any relevant `render*` -

```
validate(
  need(input$site_no %in% sites, 'Site does not exist!')
)
```

**UPDATE -**

Based on your comment, here's one approach -

```
test <- reactive({
  some inexpensive function to check if input$site_no exists in data source
  if(site exists) return("Good")
  return("Bad")
})

validate(
  need(test() == "Good", "Site does not exist!")
)
```

Comment: Thanks again - while I don't think this approach will work for my use case (there's just too many NWIS site numbers (100s of thousands) to load into the shiny app to save as a vector of valid sites), I did learn about selectInput, so appreciate it. I am going to shift to a tryCatch Error handling solution.

Comment: @JasonMatney See if my update helps. This avoids doing a one time pull of 100s of thousands of sites but now you have to deal with a function that will check with datasource every time site changes which should be okay if this function is fast. Hope this helps.